# Definition of the Intrinsic metric on a connected regular surfaces in Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry

In every book on classical differential geometry which I have opened, the intrinsic distance between two points on the surface is defined to be the infimum of lengths of the collection of piecewise-regular parametric curves in the surface, connecting the two points.

The definition makes sense because it can be shown any two points of a regular surface can be joined by a piecewise-regular parametric curve.

But is in not true that something stronger is true: that any pair of points in the regular surface can be joined by a regular parametric curve? In that case, would it not be simpler to define the intrinsic distance between two points to be the infimum of the lengths of all regular curves joining the two points?

Comment: Try taking a disk of radius $1$ (say centered at the origin) out of the plane. What is the distance from $(-2,0)$ to $(2,0)$?

Comment: It should be twice the square root of 3, together with a sixth of the circle - if I went about proving this analytically this is the number I would be looking for. When we remove the disk with its boundary included (in order to get a regular surface of what remains), I suspect the infimum will not be attained - neither by any piecewise regular curve connecting the two, nor regular curve connecting the two. However, it appears that the simpler definition which I am proposing (omitting piecewise) works well.

Comment: If you want to require smoothness, you must show that you can round corners with no expense of length. This is a bit technical.

Comment: If you know of any, would you be able to refer me to a book/lecture notes where it is shown it is possible to round corners without overall elongation, please? I was also wondering, how could we prove analytically that the distance above (when the disk is removed with its boundary) is the number I am claiming, please?